# Create dynamic views like admin's site in django

Tags: python, django

I have an application that includes some models. All models get presented in the same way on my view (table for model, model form as table for each model). At time I have three templates and three views for each model, one for presenting one for creating and one for edit-delete. What I would like is to make it more dynamic that is have thre urls for all models kind like the django admin works. I know how I can catch the content_type the model class and the get the object when all I have is just the model name but I don't know how to bind dynamically each model with the appropriate ModelForm, when adding and editing.
So what i want is

```
url(r'^(?P<model_name>/$', "ci_models.views.present", name="ci_models"),
url(r'^(?P<model_name>/add/$', "ci_models.views.model_name_add", name="ci_models-add"),
url(r'^(?P<model_name>/edit/(?P<model_id>\d+)/$', "ci_models.views.model_name_edit_delete", name="ci_models-model_name-edit-delete" ),
```

I can extract the model class from the model in a view with

```
ct = ContentType.objects.get(model=model_name)
Model = ct.model_class()
```

After this I can do queries to the database for Model. But what If i want to choose a modelform according to the Model gotten from ct_model_class(). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution would be to have a dict with your model classes as keys and the forms as values - but you probably want to expand a bit and write something more generic - a bit like `admin.ModelAdmin` - that can handle your views too.

Comment: that's what i  started doing, I guess it's the best way.

Comment: It seems that admin site is a bit too complicated :)

Comment: @Apostolos well `admin.ModelAdmin` etc could benefit from some  refactoring indeed <g> - but the point wasn't to write something as complex, just to come with something just a bit more "packaged" than a couple view functions and a model=>form dict.